# Sending json object with jquery and but receiving nil in compojure

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, clojure, compojure

I am trying to get send json from my javascript (using jquery post) to compojure. I am sure there is something simple that I am doing wrong. My javascript file (in it's entirety) looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.post("/", "foo", function(){});
});
```

my clojure server looks like:

```
(ns spendy.routes
  (:use compojure.core
        spendy.core
    ring.middleware.json-params
        [hiccup.middleware :only (wrap-base-url)])
  (:require [compojure.route :as route]
            [compojure.handler :as handler]
            [compojure.response :as response]
        [clj-json.core :as json]))

(defroutes main-routes
  (GET "/" [] (index-page))
  (POST "/" [sent-object]
    (println "got:" sent-object "from jquery")
    (json/generate-string (respond-to-ajax (json/parse-string (if sent-object sent-object "")))))
  (route/resources "/")
  (route/not-found "Page not found"))

(def app
  (-> (handler/site main-routes)
      (wrap-base-url)))
```

When I load the page I expect to get

> got: foo from jquery

but instead I get

> got: nil from jquery

What is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.post("/", {foo:"foo"}, function(){});
})
```

on the clojure side you can receive the POST variable by the name of `foo`

Answer (score 0):

I think your app definition looks a bit odd. You're calling (handler/site main-routes), then using its value as the form for the threading macro. Other route definitions I've seen look like

```
(def app 
  (-> main-routes
      wrap-base-url))
```